# Limit as x approaches infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to solve the following limit as a part of using the n-th test for convergence:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n}{7})^n$

Is it possible to massage this expression further at all (analytically), or are we just supposed to know that this approaches infinity?

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\geqslant14$, one has $\frac{n}{7}\geqslant2$ hence $\left(\frac{n}{7}\right)^n\geqslant2^n$, and this should allow you to conclude readily.